# Monitor if GPS enabled

Tags: android, android-gps

I wish to add listener if GPS enabled or not.
This code determine if it enabled:

```
private fun locationEnabled(): Boolean {
    val manager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
}
```

I wish to listen to this change, so I tried:

```
val mLocationManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    val mGnssStatusCallback = object : GnssStatus.Callback() {
        override fun onStarted() {
            super.onStarted()
            Log.d(TAG,".onStarted()")
        }

        override fun onStopped() {
            super.onStopped()
            Log.d(TAG,".onStopped()")
        }
    }

    var pop = mLocationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(mGnssStatusCallback)
```

But its not giving the result I need, it not consistent with if it enabled/disabled.

Comment: is permission add perfectly in androidManifest.xml file : 
<uses-permission android :name= "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android :name= "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Yes, they are in the manifest

Comment: after install app in android phone/virtual go to settings > applications > select app >  "app info" > "Permission" check there is location permission is showing ?